# Python accessing dictionaries within large list - Unofficial GoogleMusicAPI

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, google-music

New to python, and still learning! Although, I will always be learning!

I have this large list of dictionaries. These dictionaries are generated via the unofficial google music api, more specifically, the .py file in the link below.

https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API/blob/develop/gmusicapi/clients/mobileclient.py

I use the function `get_all_songs` and it creates the list. I have successfully outputted the data to a text file. The function states that it creates a big list of dictionaries.

I have tried every which method on here that I could find of relevance, and could not figure out how to access the dictionaries within. Each song is a dictionary. These are things I want to do:

1. Remove key pairs that don't have anything in their values from every
   dictionary. For example, the first key below in bold 'comment' has
   no key so I would remove that.
2. Grab the information from specific keys from every dictionary. For example, take the *artist* value and *play count* value from every song (every dictionary) and be able to "play" with it. Like adding all the play counts of from every song of a particular artist. http://newcoder.io/Part-2-Graph/

Here is a dictionary I pulled from the text file I created from the function. Also, I don't know why there are (`u'`)  or   (`u"`)'s before every key and value. I believe that it is just part of the information that is captured via the API. I had the hunch that those U's are messing with the structure of the dictionary. But I may be completely wrong.

```
{
    u'comment': u'', 
    u'rating': u'0', 
    u'artistId': [u'Amicfexiiup7erm7exmzdyimive'], 
    u'composer': u'', 
    u'year': 0, 
    u'creationTimestamp': u'1395972652473326', 
    u'id': u'e6c27479-1d7d-37a6-a788-52bcb8477e42', 
    u'album': u'', 
    u'totalDiscCount': 0, 
    u'title': u"Chromeo - Jealous (I Ain't With It) (The Chainsmokers Remix).mp3",
    u'recentTimestamp': u'1395972654776000', 
    u'albumArtist': u'', 
    u'trackNumber': 0, 
    u'discNumber': 0, 
    u'deleted': False, 
    u'storeId': u'Tshltra3tgk3q6ktjdxgxjtljky', 
    u'nid': u'Tshltra3tgk3q6ktjdxgxjtljky', 
    u'totalTrackCount': 0, 
    u'estimatedSize': u'3662316', 
    u'albumId': u'B4fo7oogd5ka2jfhlddjwazivlm', 
    u'beatsPerMinute': 0, 
    u'genre': u'', 
    u'playCount': 21, 
    u'artistArtRef': [{u'url': u'REMOVED LINK BECAUSE STACKOVERFLOW LIMIT'}], 
    u'kind': u'sj#track', 
    u'artist': u'Chromeo', 
    u'lastModifiedTimestamp': 
    u'1396305526006069', 
    u'clientId': u'9gG999dOb6DKkkGTcw/9GQ', 
    u'durationMillis': u'229000'
}
```

Each dictionary has essentially the same keys, so they aren't unique to the list by any means.

Sorry for the lack of brevity! Thanks for your time regardless!

Comment: The `u` prefix means those are unicode strings, it shouldn't be impacting on the dictionary at all.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense with everything I've tried thus far to either delete specific key pairs, or access specific keys within each dictionary. 

When I attempted some of the previously mentioned things I would sometimes get an error stating that it wasn't a string. Maybe because its type is actually unicode?

I've tried using the pop() function, the del operator(?), to the re.sub(), among others.

Thanks Matt.

Comment: Could you re-phrase "Access specific key values within at will so I can code a parser, or organize them so I can work with the information. For example, say I want to pull the playCount, artist name, etc to parse and graph in the vain of the python tutorial here..." please.

Comment: Of the multiple methods I've tried, this error popped up the most on me:

**TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str**

Comment: First off, unicode is not a data type but an encoding type. It shouldn't impact what you're doing. Second, popping is not a good removal method of dictionaries. You'll often get a `dictionary changed size` error or something like that. @MatthewTrevor's answer is correct: create a new one, much cleaner and safer in any case you have to backtrack. :)

Comment: I'm currently reading all the replies, I appreciate it! @s16h I have edited the second question. I hope it makes more sense now! Thanks again.

Comment: Also, based on your error, you should really read the documentation. Elements of lists and tuples are accessed using integers. Elements in dictionaries -- the value part of the key-value pair -- is accessed via strings, which is what the key is. In your dictionary above, the keys are the `artistId`, `rating`, etc. The ones on the left, basically.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I need to investigate more. My biggest issue is/was the concept of putting the two together. Having trouble with the dictionaries within the list. Alone, I can access key /values and I can access lists with integers via slices.

Thanks again, I will look up the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `get_all_songs`, it returns a list of dictionaries. You can step through the list like so:

```
songs = client.get_all_songs()
for song in songs:
    ...
```

Each time through the loop, it will pull a successive dictionary out of the list and assign it to `song`.

To clear empty keys from a dictionary, you can create a new one using only the key/value pairs that have a non-empty value:

```
clear_song = {k:v for (k,v) in song.iteritems() if v}
```

This is a dictionary comprehension, it's pretty much equivalent to:

```
clear_song = dict()
for key, value in song.iteritems():
    if value:
        clear_song[key] = value
```

It will remove any item with a non-Truthy value, like `0` and `u''`. If you only want it to remove the empty strings, then make it a more explicit test:

```
clear_song = {k:v for (k,v) in song.iteritems() if v.strip() != u''}
```

To step through all songs and produce clear songs, you can add this to the for loop above, or you can do it all in a single list comprehension:

```
clear_songs = [
    {k:v for (k,v) in song.iteritems() if v}
    for song in songs
]
```

To access a specific dictionary, you either need to know its position in the list:

```
clear_songs[77]['title'] # get the title of the 78th song in the list
```

Or you can use `filter` to find a matching dictionary:

```
filter(lambda x: x['title'] == "Chromeo - Jealous (I Ain't With It) (The Chainsmokers Remix).mp3", clear_songs)['estimatedSize'] # return '3662316'
```

You can shove that into a convenient function:

```
def find_song(key, value, songs):
    return filter(lambda x: x[key] == value, songs)
```

And call it via:

```
find_song('title', 'Chromeo - Jealous ...', clear_songs) # will return the matching dict
```

Comment: Careful with the `if v` in the dictionary comprehensions, it will remove values that are `0` which may or may not be ideal.

Comment: +1: Very good explanation, especially after updating the `if v` issue.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Remove key pairs that don't have anything in their values from the dictionaries**

To do this, you can either make the changes (deletions) to the current dictionary, or create a new dictionary with the key/value pairs of interest.

To mutate the current dictionary, assuming it's called `song_info`:

```
songs = client.get_all_songs()
for song in songs:   
    for key, value in song.items():
        if value == u'':
            del song[key]
```

To create a new dictionary with the key/value pairs of interest:

```
songs = client.get_all_songs()
songs_without_empty_values = []
for song in songs:
    new_song_info = {key : song[key]
                     for key in song.items()
                     if song[key] != u''}
    songs_without_empty_values.append(new_song_info)
```

You can alter the `if`s appropriately depending on what exactly your definition of 'no value' is; I've assumed anything with `u''` (i.e. empty string).

**2. Grab the information from specific keys from every dictionary**

I'm still a bit unsure of the exact requirement here.

Assuming you want to go through all the dictionaries and get a list of all the play counts, then:

```
songs = client.get_all_songs()
key = u'playCount'
values = [song[key] for song in songs]
```

Note that the code above is very simple and it does not account for the `KeyError` being raised if `key` is not in a dictionary.

Comment: I am going to do both Matthews, as well as your solution just to learn to get both working.

Trying your method, I get this error. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Here is a snippet of the code.

`songs = api.get_all_songs()

    new_song_info = {key : songs[key]
                    for key in songs.items()
                    if songs[key] != u''}

    out = open('songs4.txt', 'w')
    out.write("%r \n" % songs)`

I cannot seem to format this in the comments properly using the "`code`" markdown(?)

Comment: The answer to the first question is for "a dictionary (can then be applied to each dictionary)". So you need to iterate over the list elements and do what you have done. I'll change the answer to be clearer.